# Is there Google Cloud Storage emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

For the purpose of testing, I would like to mock Cloud Storage because it slows tests down.

Is there Google Cloud Storage emulator?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56804018/209288 they are possibly developing one now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't an official emulator provided by Google for the time being.

I'm currently using project Minio (https://www.minio.io/) for mocking Google Storage's behavior in development (Minio uses the filesystem as storage backend and provides compatibility with S3 apiV2, which is compatible with Google Storage).

Comment: Can you provide some details on the setup please?

Comment: I would also be happy if you can provide some details. Are you able to create a Storage/Bucket reference that points to the local MinIO instance? Or you just mock out the service which calls the Cloud Storage APIs and you store the files via the mock service?

Comment: I don't have access to the project setup anymore, but since I answered this questions Google has developed an emulator for Storage: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/TESTING.md#testing-code-that-uses-storage

Comment: That emulator seems to be just a java class implementing the cloud storage interface of the java client, so it's really just dedicated to java developers

Comment: The file mentioned by Caio was deleted, the latest version is: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/a29a7cf422a2263b796bc21b2304701d322f0217/TESTING.md#testing-code-that-uses-storage

Answer (score 42):

Google has an [in-memory emulator](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage-nio) you can use (majority of core functions are implemented).

You need `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-nio` on your test classpath (`:0.25.0-alpha` currently).  Then you can use/inject `Storage` interface implemented by the in-memory `LocalStorageHelper` test-helper service.

Example usage:

```
  import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
  import com.google.cloud.storage.contrib.nio.testing.LocalStorageHelper;

  @Test
  public void exampleInMemoryGoogleStorageTest() {
    Storage storage = LocalStorageHelper.getOptions().getService();

    final String blobPath = "test/path/foo.txt";
    final String testBucketName = "test-bucket";
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(
        BlobId.of(testBucketName, blobPath)
    ).build();

    storage.create(blobInfo, "randomContent".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Iterable<Blob> allBlobsIter = storage.list(testBucketName).getValues();
    // expect to find the blob we saved when iterating over bucket blobs
    assertTrue(
        StreamSupport.stream(allBlobsIter.spliterator(), false)
            .map(BlobInfo::getName)
            .anyMatch(blobPath::equals)
    );
  }
```