# Emulate Google Cloud Storage in local/dev kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, emulation, development-environment

I’m working on an application that will use Google Cloud Storage to save files and I was wondering: what’s the best way to emulate it for development?

The application will run on kubernetes, and I was planning to run a development environment on my machine using Minikube (or similar). I know I can set up a different storage for development purposes but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid charges and most important to be able to work offline.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage [free trial for GCP](https://cloud.google.com/free/), which gives you $300 of credit for start.

Alternatively you could use [in memory emulator](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/TESTING.md#on-your-machine-2) - This is just available with the java library only.

Comment: I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542530/is-there-google-cloud-storage-emulator) that suggests [minio](https://github.com/minio/minio) but I haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative since a few days: https://pypi.org/project/gcloud-storage-emulator/

Although it is still in its early fase, it could be a viable alternative when using python.