# Can I run Firebase Storage cloud functions locally?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

From [Firebase DOCS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator):

> **Run functions locally**
>
> The Firebase CLI includes a Cloud Functions emulator which can emulate the following function types:
>
> - HTTPS functions
> - Callable functions
> - Cloud Firestore functions
>
> You can run functions locally to test them before deploying to production.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to run cloud functions for Firebase Storage (ex: triggered by file upload) locally or do I need to actually deploy them for testing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*firebaser here*

**Update**: the Firebase Emulator Suite now also supports Cloud Storage. This includes uploads to emulated Cloud Storage triggering emulated Cloud Functions.

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) for full details.

Comment: I'll submit one as well, but why would firebase release the emulator suite without the storage as an emulator? A firebase blog post about the issue would have been a great idea.

Comment: We're developing the emulator suite in the open, so that we can make it available quickly to developers. While I have no doubt that more developers will be helped when it also emulates storage, many developers are already helped by having it available today without storage (or auth, which is a more frequent request). Keep an eye out on the release notes for feature updates, or... you can monitor the commits on Github of course. :)

Comment: I appreciate your response and followed you on twitter. Have always appreciated your presence in stack overflow. That said, I didn't even think about auth until I tried running my own functions and found it wasn't available. It's great to hear that the storage and auth emulators are definitely in the works. I guess personally see the difficulty in testing code without the storage/auth emulators for my situation. However, I will admit unit testing isn't something I'm use to. Have any suggestions for unit testing? Testing overall to achieve the same end result? Thank you, btw

Comment: For anyone who would like to monitor the github, https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/tree/master/src/emulator. Thanks @Frank

Comment: We recently had an episide on unit testing with the emulators here: https://firebaseonair.withgoogle.com/events/firebase-live20/watch?talk=security-rules-with-emulator-suite

Comment: And here is the actual ticket for the Storage Emulator Feature request: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1738 go upvote it!

Answer (score 4):

Storage has been implemented in firebase tools 9.11.0. I just took it for a test run, and I found that functions running in the emulator are, indeed, triggered by uploads to the emulated storage.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1738#issuecomment-843256335