# I cannot run my Firebase storage functions on the Firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Today i ran into a problem with my Firebase Cloud Function that generates images sizes when new images are being uploaded to the Firebase Storage. This problem causes my quota to exceed after a couple uploads and when the quota exceeds the limit i am not able to use firebase anymore. Now i am trying to run this Cloud Function locally so that my quota will not exceed.

I tried running the emulator in my terminal with this command: `firebase emulators:start`

This initializes all my Cloud Functions except my Firebase Auth and Firebase Storage functions. The [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) say the emulator only supports:

- HTTPS functions
- Callable functions
- Cloud Firestore functions

Is there a way/work around so i can run my Firebase Storage and Firebase Auth functions locally?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56804018/209288 and links to the feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the emulator, no.  As you've seen, they're just not supported.

Look into invoking functions using the [functions shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell), or [unit testing your functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) with the functions-test module.